# Build complete own FrontEnd for RocketChat possible?

Tags: rocket.chat

I would like to integrate Rocket.Chat into my website. I found out, that I can embed RocketChat via iframe and customize the style with the built in "Embedded Layout". However I would like to so to say build my own Web-Frontend-Client for a Rocket.Chat-Server with PHP and jQuery. Is that possible? So let us say I have 2 VMs running on my server, one for my homepage, one for Rocket.Chat. Could I somehow access the Rocket.Chat Server via jQuery Websocket Connection or with the Rocket.Chat API and login users and get and write messages (private and channel)? If yes, is there any documentation or example on this out there? Thank you very much.